# selecting from derived table in MySql

Tags: mysql, derived-table

I have a table `T` like this:

```
ID | column 1 | column 2 |...| column n
```

Here ID is not a primary key.
I performed some operation and group the results according to ID so I get a table `T1` like this:

```
ID | column 1 | column 2 |...| column x
```

Now some IDs which were present in `T` are eliminated in `T1` due to above operation.
Now I want to again do some operation on `T`, and again want to group result according to `ID` but only those IDs which are listed in `T1`.
How can I do it in MySql ?

Answer (score -1):

What kind of operation you performed?

If you join these two tables simply create an alias for each id like that

```
SELECT t.id AS id_1, t1.id AS id_2 FROM t LEFT JOIN t1 ON ......
```

then you have ids from both tables id_1 from table T and id_2 from table T1

Comment: I don't have T1 stored. I need a single query from T which uses a derived table T1.

Comment: can you paste your query which returns table T1